# ASP.NET MVC - Current Selected value doesnt get selected in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my Action for Editing an item in my model I have:

```
ViewBag.PossibleSource = context.Source.ToList();
```

In my View I have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SourceID, ((IEnumerable<btn_intranet.Areas.DayBook.Models.DayBookSource>)ViewBag.PossibleSource).Select(option => new SelectListItem
       {
           Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.SourceName),
           Value = option.SourceID.ToString(),
           Selected = (Model != null) && (option.SourceID == Model.SourceID)
       }))
```

In Chrome this works as expected. When I pass a model to my view, the current value that's set in my model is the selected value in the list. But in IE8 and 9 it's selected value is the ORIGINAL value my model was set as even though the update does work. So if I selected "hello" originally and then edited to "world". In chrome when i reload the page it will be set to "world" but in IE "hello" is selected in the dropdown even tho "world" is set in my database for my model. It is worth noting these are updated via AJAX

EDIT:

Ajax.Actionlink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.ItemNumber, "EditItem", new { id = item.QuoteLineID, enquiryId = item.EnquiryID }, new AjaxOptions()
       {
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
           UpdateTargetId = "EditItem"
       })
```

This loads the form onto the view.

Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditItem", new { controller = "QuoteLines" }, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "Summary"
    }, new { @class = "manual-search cf" }))
{
  ...Other Model inputs

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SourceID, ((IEnumerable<btn_intranet.Areas.DayBook.Models.DayBookSource>)ViewBag.PossibleSource).Select(option => new SelectListItem
       {
           Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.SourceName),
           Value = option.SourceID.ToString(),
           Selected = (Model != null) && (option.SourceID == Model.SourceID)
       }))
      <input type="submit" class="update-items" value="Update Line" />
}
```

EditItem Action GET request:

```
public virtual ActionResult EditItem(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                DayBookQuoteLines q = context.QuoteLines.Single(x => x.QuoteLineID == id);
                ViewBag.PossibleSource = context.Source.ToList();
                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return PartialView("_EditItem", q);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("SalesDetails", new { controller = "Enquiries", id = q.EnquiryID });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return PartialView("_Error", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

EditItem Action POST request:

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult EditItem(DayBookQuoteLines q)
        {
            try
            {

                ViewBag.PossibleSource = context.Source.ToList();

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    context.Entry(q).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    return PartialView("_GetSummary", context.Vehicles.Where(x => x.EnquiryID == q.EnquiryID).ToList());
                }
                return PartialView("_EditItem", q);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return PartialView("_Error", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you have some javascript error or something? Can you show some code?

Comment: I literally have an Ajax Form and an Ajax link to show the form

Comment: Would have been nice to see a narrowed down versions of your Model, Controller and View that would allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I made an edit, If you want to see my get/post requests i'll post them too

Comment: I've included my action's for my GET and POST request

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say `when I reload the page`. How are you reloading the page? F5? AJAX?

Comment: I've fixed it. It was a Cache issue. I made my Ajax.Actionlink a POST request and changed my EditItem GET action to EditItemGet and it fixed it

Comment: It was both, I tried F5 and by clicking on the Ajax link again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, I renamed my GET request for EditItem to EditItemGet and then in my @Ajax.ActionLink I did:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(item.ItemNumber, "EditItemGet", new { id = item.QuoteLineID, enquiryId = item.EnquiryID }, new AjaxOptions()
           {
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               UpdateTargetId = "EditItem",
               HttpMethod = "POST"
           })
```

It was a Cache issue. Thats why it only failed in IE which likes Cache. I read before that making the request a POST request prevents Caching.